# How to make simple nested listed views in React Native from objects

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, react-native

I have an array of objects like this:

```
const user = [
        {
            "firstName": "John",
            "lastName": "Doe",
            "date": "19 March 2018"
        },
        {
            "firstName": "Anna",
            "lastName": "Smith",
             "date": "19 March 2018"
        },
        {
            "firstName": "Peter",
            "lastName": "Jones",
            "date": "19 March 2018"
        },
         {
            "firstName": "Turbulent",
            "lastName": "Flow ",
            "date": "20 March 2018"
        },
        {
            "firstName": "Anna-subsonic",
            "lastName": "Raleigh",
             "date": "20 March 2018"
        },
        {
            "firstName": "Jeremiah",
            "lastName": "Heir",
             "date": "20 March 2018"
        }
        {
            "firstName": "Peter",
            "lastName": "BioMass",
            "date": "21 March 2018"
        },
    ];
```

And I want to create a nested listed based on the dates, something dat would look like this:

```
Data for 19 March 2018  //listView Header
John Doe
Anna Smith 
Peter Jones
Date for 20 March 2018
Turbulent Flow
Anna-subsonic Raleigh
Jeremiah Heir
Date for 21 March 2018
Peter BioMass
```

Please I just want to know how to loop through each user.date and how to use LISTVIEW to display it as so. 
I'm not very good at objects please, and I'm new to React Native. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

With [`JS#reducers`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) or other looping technique you can do it.

```
const dateWiseUser = user.reduce((userDatewise, { firstName,lastName,date }) => {

  if (!userDatewise[date]) userDatewise[date] = [];
    userDatewise[date].push(`${firstName} ${lastName}`);
    return userDatewise;
}, {});
```

Now,use the `dateWiseUser` in ListView as a `dataSource` attribute value.

**#[`ListView`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/listview.html)**

```
<ListView
        style={styles.container}
        dataSource={dateWiseUser}
        renderRow={(data) => <Row {...data} />}
      />
```

**Row**  Sateless  component

```
const Row = (props) => (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <Text style={styles.text}>
      {`${props.{firstName}} ${props.lastName}`}
    </Text>
  </View>
);
```

Comment: I'm not very good at redux and reducers. Can't I use some sort of looping

Comment: you can use for in loop even.

Comment: All I know how to do, is using the react native documentation to create a listview with a header... Please Forgive my bad programming skills, I was thinking about creating a new object for dates or instalingl react-native-nested-listviews

Comment: How do I do that? @RIYAJ KHAN

Comment: @Miss1900f5 if you're not good with programming, why do you use React?, why not only js or jQuery to learn the basics?

Comment: If I was very good, I won't be asking. Is that not the very essence of learning @Ele . Help me with the way to go about it if you can.

Comment: @Miss1900f5 I'm not talking about that.  My concern is about using a Framework which needs that you handle js very well.  Good luck!

Comment: @Miss1900f5 I'm also from a third world country `:)` -  Sorry if I was tough.  Have a good day!

Comment: @RIYAJKHAN Its not working. Please, here is a link from snack.expo.io